# installation of magento 2.1.1 fails

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm trying to install **Magento 2.1.1** on **unix server** but when it does system check I keep on getting following error message and application will not install.

> Your PHP Version is 5.6.22, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.

After using:

```
phpinfo();
```

I get:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path      `/opt/alt/php56/etc`

Loaded Configuration File         `/home/some9753/public_html/php.ini`

Scan this dir for additional .ini files         `/opt/alt/php56/link/conf`

Additional .ini files parsed       `/opt/alt/php56/link/conf/alt_php.ini`

I don't have access to the directories `/opt/alt/php56/etc`, apart from that in the php info file a`lways_populate_raw_post_data` is set to -1 for Local Value as well as Master Value.

The Loaded Configuration File `php.ini` was created by myself and and placed in public_html folder. It contains:

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1;
```

But it is not solving problem. I don't know how the installer is coming up with `always_populate_raw_post_data = 0` when it is not set to that value anywhere. Any suggestion as to what I should do to solve problem? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you check the info showing when using phpinfo(); is that always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 ?

Comment: Ye, it is always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing always_populate_raw_post_data you will need to restart the server for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

When  faced this problem I did the following steps do as described

1. Set the **php version** of the system to the latest one.
2. Open **`php.ini`** file & enable the **php_intl.dll** by removing the coma before the name.
3. Restarted the sever.

It starts working!

Answer (score -1):

You can edit a file in Ubuntu not having direct permission using command line editor `sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini`

It will open a editor and you can fetch `always_populate_raw_post_data = 0;`
and change it to `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1;`